# Javascript chained inequality gives bizarre results

Tags: javascript

```
(0 <= 0 <= 0) === false
(-1 < 0 <= 0 <= 0) === true
```

What's going on here? Does Javascript actually have inequality chaining that's just wrong in some cases?

Comment: Ah, you're right Felix. Sorry about that; I searched for a while before posting, but didn't see that one. Is there any way I, as the other, can close it as a duplicate directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typed up the question and then was struck by the answer. Javascript does not have inequality chaining. Rather, `0 <= 0 <= 0` becomes `true <= 0`, which is evaluated as `1 <= 0`. Indeed, `0 < 0 <= 0` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no chaining of operator but [**precedence**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Here all the operators have the same priority so the operations are done from left to right.

When your comparison involves a boolean, [the MDN explains how the comparison works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) :

> If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to
>   1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.

This means the first operation is decomposed according to priorities as

```
((0 <= 0) <= 0)
```

which is

```
true <= false
```

which is

```
false
```

And the second one is

```
(true <= 0) <= 0
```

which is

```
false <= 0
```

which is `true`.