# JavaScript comparison operators issue : using 2 operators consecutively :why in JavaScript (12>11&&11>=10) does not equal to (12>11>=10)

Tags: javascript, performance, console, console.log, comparison-operators

like normal math, I tried to log this code in the console and I expected to get the value `true`

```
 console.log(12>11>=10)
```

but what I got was `false`
however when I tried to log `console.log(12>11&&11>=10)` I got `true`
so for the last time, I tried `console.log( (12>11&&11>=10) == (12>11>=10) )`and i got flase

### so my question is :

**why in javascript  (12>11&&11>=10)  does not equal to  (12>11>=10) ?!**

and I hope anyone can help

Comment: Because you're asking if `true >= 10`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a number is between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718561/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-between-two-values)

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript chained inequality gives bizarre results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466099/javascript-chained-inequality-gives-bizarre-results). Alternatively, [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089284/4642212), or pick any of its [linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/4089284).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because programming language syntax and human intuition are two *very* different things.  At no point will the language "know what you mean", you have to be completely explicit and unambigous.

What you have here are two operations.  One using the `>` operator and one using the `>=` operator.  Operations are atomic things.  One will happen, then the other.

So this:

```
12 > 11
```

Results in this:

```
true
```

And then this:

```
true >= 10
```

Results in this:

```
false
```

Use less intuition and more logic.  Separate your two operations:

```
12 > 11
11 >= 10
```

And combine them logically:

```
(12 > 11) && (11 >= 10)
```

Which will evaluate to:

```
true && true
```

Which will evaluate to:

```
true
```

Comment: thank you I'm used to working with python so I didn't know the way that javascript will interpret this code (the successive 2 operators )by

Answer (score 0):

Because of the bindings of the operators > and >= are the same this is handled as:

```
(12>10)>=10
```

Which means:

```
true>=10
```

And this is `false`.